# State Update in Parent Not Triggering Re-Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's something fundamental I'm missing about how React triggers re-render when state is updated in a parent.

See attached codepen:
https://codepen.io/esoteric43/pen/poVPROQ

```
class App extends React.Component {

  initState() {
    let states = {}
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
      states[i] = { selectedStatus: 'unselected'}
    }
    return states;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 

    this.state = {
      states: this.initState()  
    };

    this.updateStates = this.updateStates.bind(this);
  }

  updateStates(s) {
    this.setState({
      states: s
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StateSelections states={this.state.states} updateStates={this.updateStates}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class StateSelections extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      stateSelections: [
        <StateSelectionWrapper key={1} states={this.props.states} updateStates={this.props.updateStates}/> ,
        <StateSelectionWrapper key={2} states={this.props.states} updateStates={this.props.updateStates}/> 
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.stateSelections}
      </div>

    );

  }

}

class StateSelectionWrapper extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StateSelection states={this.props.states} updateStates={this.props.updateStates} />
      </div>
    )
    }
}

class StateSelection extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.executeCallback = (c) => props.updateStates(c);
  }

  handleClick(s) {
    let copiedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.states));
    //let copiedState = this.props.states;

    if (copiedState[s].selectedStatus === 'unselected') {
      copiedState[s].selectedStatus = 'selected';
    } else {
      copiedState[s].selectedStatus = 'unselected';
    }

    this.executeCallback(copiedState);
  }

  renderState(s) {

    if (this.props.states == null) {
      return;
    }


    let color;
    if (this.props.states[s].selectedStatus === 'unselected' ) {
      color = 'white';
    } else {
      color = 'red';
    }

    return (
      <S key={s} value={s} color={color} onClick={() => this.handleClick(s)} />
    )
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>

        {this.renderState(0)}
        {this.renderState(1)}
        {this.renderState(2)}
        {this.renderState(3)}
        {this.renderState(4)}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function S(props) {
  return (
    <button style={{backgroundColor: props.color}} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.value}</button>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

When handleClick is called, the cells in both rows should be updated to red since both classes use the same state from the parent. The code is setting the states' selectedStatus to 'selected' and passing the state values to the executeCallback method which is indeed calling the parent's updateStates function. Unfortunately setState isn't triggering a re-render of the view.

I'm missing something about how to share state among two children and how to get those children to update when the parent's state is updated.

Comment: `<StateSelections />` renders cached `<StateSelectionWrapper />`. Once they're created it doesn't care about the `props` anymore because it will always return stored value.

Comment: Components are not appropriate state values. State should be the absolute minimum stateful data that is required to render the UI. Remove the state from StateSelections and render two StateSelectionWrappers instead.

Comment: The example is distilled from another bit of code where the wrapper adds additional functionality removed here for brevity. I'm not quire following the recommendation to remove state from StateSelections since it has no state. It only uses props from what I can tell.

Comment: *"... to remove state from StateSelections since it has no state. It only uses props from what I can tell."* @Esoteric you sure about that? `this.state = { stateSelections: [ ... ] }` and `return (<div>{this.state.stateSelections}</div>);`

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct there is state in the StateSelections class. What I'm eventually attempting to do with StateSelections is allow dynamic addition and deletion of StateSelectionWrapper. For now, I've just hard-coded two items, but the eventual idea is to allow the addition or removal of these via a button click. Interestingly, when I just output two StateSelectionWrappers in the return call, I get the behavior I'm looking for. It's just when attempting to allow for a more dynamic nature that I'm missing something...

Comment: Is it just a matter of 'lifting state up' ie putting the list of StateSelectionWrapper into the parent (App)?